# Create profile picture uploader in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have recently started working on zend framework. I want to upload a profile picture and rename & re-size it. Am using the code below. with this am able to upload but am not able to rename and am not getting a way to re-size the uploaded file.

if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
            {

```
            if(!$objProfilePictureForm->isValid($_POST))
            {
                //return $this->render('add');

            }

            if(!$objProfilePictureForm->profile_pic->receive())
            {
                $this->view->message = '<div class="popup-warning">Errors Receiving File.</div>';


            }

            if($objProfilePictureForm->profile_pic->isUploaded())
            {
                $values = $objProfilePictureForm->getValues();
                $source = $objProfilePictureForm->profile_pic->getFileName();


                //to re-name the image, all you need to do is save it with a new name, instead of the name they uploaded it with. Normally, I use the primary key of the database row where I'm storing the name of the image. For example, if it's an image of Person 1, I call it 1.jpg. The important thing is that you make sure the image name will be unique in whatever directory you save it to.

                $new_image_name = 'new';

                //save image to database and filesystem here
                $image_saved = move_uploaded_file($source, '../uploads/thumb'.$new_image_name);
                if($image_saved)
                {
                    $this->view->image = '<img src="../uploads/'.$new_image_name.'" />';
                    $objProfilePictureForm->reset();//only do this if it saved ok and you want to re-display the fresh empty form
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Rename a file while uploading, you will have to add the "Rename-Filter" to your file-form-element. The class is called `Zend_Filter_File_Rename`.

```
// Create the form
$form = new Zend_Form();

// Create an configure the file-element
$file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
$file->setDestination('my/prefered/path/to/the/file') // This is the path where you want to store the uploaded files.
$file->addFilter('Rename', array('target' => 'my_new_filename.jpg')); // This is for the filename
$form->addElement($file);

// Submit-Button
$form->addElement(new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('save');

// Process postdata
if($this->_request->isPost())
{
    // Get the file and store it within the specified destination with the specified name.
    $file->receive();
}
```

To make the filename dynamically you may name it with a timestamp or something. You may also apply the Rename-filter within your post-data-processing before the call of `$file->receive()`. This could be useful if you insert a row into a table and want to name the file with the id of the just inserted row.

Since you want to store a profile picture you could get the id of the user from your db and name the pic with that id.

Comment: thanks faileN! can u plz tell me how can we make the file name dynamic and can ve move the file to some other location